# How to show the modal view when clicking on a lookup field?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I have 2  list that linked by a lookup column.

When i clicked a item of list show dispform on modal popup.

Problem is:when i click on lookup field it is open a new page.

I want show on modal popup.

in share point designer

```
<xsl:value-of select="@MailID" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```

if i change disable-output-escaping="no", in page show

```
<a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http://mysite/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={0E7E5CF1-7382-4E32-83D0-11A298365781}&ID=12', RefreshPage); return false;" href="http://mysite/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={0E7E5CF1-7382-4E32-83D0-11A298365781}&ID=12">12</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my answer :)

Id of lookup field :

```
substring-before(substring-after(@MailID, 'ID='), '&#038;')
```

and title of lookup field :

```
substring-after(@MailID, '&gt;'), '&lt;')
```

and use Popup

```
onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http://mysite/_layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={0E7E5CF1-7382-4E32-83D0-11A298365781}&ID={substring-before(substring-after(@MailID, 'ID='), '&#038;')}', RefreshPage); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Default xsl tag for lookup field looks like
`<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@*[name()=current()/@Name]" disable-output-escaping="yes">`     try it.
PS: about disable-output-escaping.. "yes" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be output as is. "no" indicates that special characters (like "<") should be output as "<".

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i get error ! "A reference to variable or parameter 'thisNode' cannot be resolved. The variable or parameter may not be defined, or it may not be in scope."

Comment: try "./@*[name()=current()/@Name]" instead

Comment: No, it is not work :(